# Function in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, sql-function

So I was trying to create a function

```
Edit: Deleted this and created a new code
```

I'm getting an error Warning: Function created with compilation errors.
So guidance would be helpful. And I would be helpful if you can inform how to execute it

EDIT: created a new code to return same error

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION EmpNoFunc(p_empno IN Employee01.EmpNo%TYPE)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS Emp_Detail VARCHAR2(130);
BEGIN
SELECT 'E_Name-'|| Employee01.EName ||,
'Job-'|| Employee01.Job ||, 'Hired-'|| Employee01.HiredDate ||,
INTO Emp_Detail
FROM Employee01
WHERE EmpNo = p_empno;
RETURN(Emp_Detail);
END EmpNoFunc;
/
```

Errors are -

```
5/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/39     PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression
```

But can't seem to solve it.

Comment: You need to store the result of that SELECT somewhere. And you are missing a `RETURN` statement in your function.

Comment: What should I `RETURN`

Comment: It depends on what you want. Why did you create a function? Its purpose is to return *something*. If you don't want to do that (return that *something*), you probably don't need a function at all. Consider stored procedure, instead.

Comment: @LittleFoot can you check the edited new code

Comment: You are selecting 3 columns into 1 variable. Try to get the basic understanding of how it is supposed to work. Best place to start is the documentation: google "oracle SELECT INTO" or https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/selectinto_statement.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close; a working example on a table similar to yours (Scott's EMP):

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION empnofunc (p_empno IN emp.empno%TYPE)
  2     RETURN VARCHAR2
  3  IS
  4     emp_detail  VARCHAR2 (130);
  5  BEGIN
  6     SELECT    'EName-'
  7            || e.ename
  8            || ', Job-'
  9            || e.job
 10            || ', Hired-'
 11            || e.hiredate
 12       INTO emp_detail
 13       FROM emp e
 14      WHERE e.empno = p_empno;
 15
 16     RETURN (emp_detail);
 17  END empnofunc;
 18  /

Function created.

SQL> SELECT empnofunc (empno) result
  2    FROM emp
  3   WHERE empno = 7369;

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
EName-SMITH, Job-CLERK, Hired-17.12.80

SQL>
```